# What is the purpose of Anchors in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, anchor

Say I drew an arrow as

```latex
\draw [thick, ->] (0,0) -- ++(2, 0);
```

and now I want to give that arrow a label, $v$, at its tip using a `node` as

```latex
\draw [thick, ->] (0,0) -- ++(2, 0) node[right]{$v$};
```

This works perfectly well; however, I have also seen the use of "anchors" which have a similar effect

```latex
\draw [thick, ->] (0,0) -- ++(2, 0) node[anchor=west]{$v$};
```

It isn't clear to me what this anchor solution is doing differently than the first solution. It also doesn't make sense to me why "west" puts the anchor on the right... west is to the left not the right.

Comment: quite right  -- the anchor is created to the left of `v` -- now try `anchor=south` and `anchor = north` see where the anchor is created with reference to `v`

Answer (score 9):

The purpose of the anchor is that if you say

```
\path (x,y) node[anchor=<anchor>]{...};
```

then the anchor `<anchor>` of the node is at the point `(x,y)`. These anchors can be directions like `west`, angles, i.e. numbers, and things like `base`. In the way you use `anchor=west` and `right`, they do have the same effect. To see this, let us look up the options in `tikz.code.tex`.

```
\tikzoption{anchor}{\def\tikz@anchor{#1}\let\tikz@do@auto@anchor=\relax}%

\tikzoption{right}[]{\def\tikz@anchor{west}\tikz@possibly@transform{x}{}{#1}}%
```

As you can see, if you use `right` without an argument, it is equivalent to `anchor=west`. The difference is that you can give `right` an argument, a distance that indicates how far right the node will be.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily]
 \path (0,2) node[anchor=west]{anchor=west} 
  (0,1) node[right]{right} 
  (0,0) node[right=1cm]{right=1cm} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]